# error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

What is wrong with my bar plot?
The bar plot is not displaying when I am using variable names on this y axis
`y = [totalMales, totalFemales]  # if I input numerical values it works, but it doesn't with variable names`

```
#check total number of males
totalMales = newDF.loc[(newDF.Gender=='Male')].count #409
print("totalMales" + str(totalMales))


totalFemales = newDF.loc[(newDF.Gender=='Female')].count()  #77
print("totalFemales" + str(totalFemales))

#males are more likely to borrow than females 409 > 77

plt.style.use('ggplot')

x = ['Males', 'Females']
y = [totalMales, totalFemales]  # if I input numerical values it works, but it doesn't with variable names

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

plt.bar(x_pos, y, color='green')
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("Total who Paid Off")
plt.title("Number of Males vs Females who Paid Off")

plt.xticks(x_pos, x)

plt.show()
```

[image: image plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is a method, change to this (similarly for `totalFemale`):

```
totalMales = newDF.loc[(newDF.Gender=='Male'), 'Gender'].count()
```

Also you can do:

```
newDF.groupby('Gender').size().plot.bar()
```

or

```
newDF['Gender'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Comment: I checked the type of  ```totalMales```  and ```totalFemale``` and it's int64, so what  is wrong with count()?

Comment: I've corrected it, but now I get "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" | ```https://gist.github.com/bibscy/5aa0d1cba753773bb88d1929a819309e```

Comment: `newDF.count()` returns a series with dtype `int64`, not a single number. See update for `totalMales`.

Comment: Ok, ```totalMales = newDF.loc[(newDF.Gender=='Male'), 'Gender'].count()``` what is  the role of ```Gender``` argument ( after the round brancket) in this expression? To what field does it map to? I understand that ```newDF.loc[(newDF.Gender=='Male')``` selects ```Male``` from column ```newDF.Gender```, but what is the role of the second argument ```'Gnder]'```

Comment: the second `Gender` indicates the column. So the command only select one column ('Gender') to count.

Answer (score 1):

While you are having a DataFrame it is possible to use more build in functions. With the `value_counts` the different values in a certain column are counted and returned as a Series. Using `.plot.bar()` this could directly be plotted in the bar chart. The labels on the x-as are directly the different Genders.

```
    # Count the values
    gender_count = newDF.Gender.value_counts()
    
    # Create plot
    gender_count.plot.bar()
    
    # Settings for plot
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.xlabel("Gender")
    plt.ylabel("Total who Paid Off")
    plt.title("Number of Males vs Females who Paid Off")
    plt.show()
```